# Beamer Presentation References slide can't allowframebreaks and have \frametitle

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, natbib, frame-title

I am writing a Beamer presentation and my references are too long for one frame. So I tried to use `[allowframebreaks]`, but then I get the *TeX capacity exceeded error* if I have a `\frametitle`. I can have either frame breaks or the title, but not both. I am using `natbib` and `pdflatex` on ShareLaTeX.com.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[14pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usemintedstyle{trac}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}



\title{The Prospects of D-T Nuclear Fusion as a Source of Electricity Production}
\subtitle{A Senior Seminar}
\date{23 April 2015}
\author{Kyle Reilly}
\institute{Cedarville University}



\graphicspath{{figures/}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}

\footnotesize{
\bibliography{Seminar_References.bib}
}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) which reproduces your problem without access to your .bib file and theme

Comment: Are you sure it is due to `\frametitle`? I compiled your code after removing the bibliography and putting in a lot of dummy text (`lipsum`). The document compiles fine with automatic frame breaks occuring.  May be the problem is with your `.bbl` or `.bib` files. (See if the following MWE compiles in your system)

Comment: `\documentclass[14pt, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\lipsum

\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: Besides neither having the theme nor the bib file, the above example works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `allowframebreaks` option sometimes requires you to `\protect` the frametitle.

<strike>You should make the following change to your document:</strike>

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{\protect References} % \protect the title here

  \footnotesize{
    \bibliography{Seminar_References.bib}
  }

\end{frame}
```

If you want to understand more about why you need `\protect`, check out the discussion in [What's the difference between Fragile and Robust?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

Edit: Apologies, `\protect` doesn't have the intended effect at this level of the compilation. You could try the following work-around by editing the lines in `beamerthemem.sty` with the `\protect` command:

```
  281: \protect\insertframetitle%
  284: \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\protect\insertframetitle}}%
```

Here is a working example.

demo.tex:

```
\documentclass[14pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usemintedstyle{trac}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\title{The Prospects of D-T Nuclear Fusion as a Source of Electricity Production}
\subtitle{A Senior Seminar}
\date{23 April 2015}
\author{Kyle Reilly}
\institute{Cedarville University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}

Force the frame break \citet{Knuth92} \citet{ConcreteMath} \citet{Simpson} \citet{Er01} \citet{greenwade93}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}

\bibliography{demo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

demo.bib:

```
@article{Knuth92, 
        author = "D.E. Knuth", 
        title = "Two notes on notation", 
        journal = "Amer. Math. Monthly", 
        volume = "99", 
        year = "1992", 
        pages = "403--422", 
} 

@book{ConcreteMath, 
        author = "R.L. Graham and D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik", 
        title = "Concrete mathematics", 
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley", 
        address = "Reading, MA", 
        year = "1989" 
} 

@unpublished{Simpson, 
        author = "H. Simpson", 
        title = "Proof of the {R}iemann {H}ypothesis", 
        note = "preprint (2003), available at  
        \texttt{http://www.math.drofnats.edu/riemann.ps}", 
        year = "2003" 
} 

@incollection{Er01, 
        author = "P. Erd{\H o}s", 
        title = "A selection of problems and results in combinatorics", 
        booktitle = "Recent trends in combinatorics (Matrahaza, 1995)", 
        publisher = "Cambridge Univ. Press", 
        address = "Cambridge", 
        pages = "1--6", 
        year = "2001" 
} 
@article{greenwade93, 
    author  = "George D. Greenwade", 
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})", 
    year    = "1993", 
    journal = "TUGBoat", 
    volume  = "14", 
    number  = "3", 
    pages   = "342--351" 
}
```

[image: Title page]
[image: Presentation body with citations]
[image: References, page one]
[image: References, page two]

Comment: I'm not sure this can solve the problem, as `\protect` is doing nothing.